# Question about putting an upper bound on a particular operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

So according to Wikipedia, given V(f)(t) = $\int_0^t f(s)ds$ where $f(s) \in L^2 (0,1)$ and $t \in (0,1)$. They say that $||V|| = \frac{2}{\pi}$ and I have seen the proof of this on a MSE post. The problem I am working on asks us to show $||V|| \le$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. Now I understand if we can prove $||V||  \le \frac{2}{\pi}$ then we are done, but the proof I saw seemed a little bit tricky and I suspect that directly showing $||V|| \le$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ is easier.

We know that $||V||^2 = \int_0^1|\int_0^t f(s)ds|^2$dt but not sure where to go from here to reach the goal of showing $||V|| \le$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz is your friend :) :
Starting from your equality
$$||V(f)||^2=\int_0^1 |\int_0^t f(s)ds|^2dt$$

With CS inequality :
$$(\int_0^t f(s)ds)^2\leq \int_0^t ds \int_0^t f(s)^2ds\leq t||f||_2^2$$

Then :
$$||V(f)||^2\leq \int_0^1 t dt ||f||_2^2=\frac{1}{2} ||f||^2_2$$

Hence $|||V|||\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$